# Postfix not sending emails outside

Tags: linux, email, raspberry-pi, postfix, telnet

so I'm trying to run a postfix app on my raspberry pi 4 following this tutorial: https://raspberrytips.com/mail-server-raspberry-pi/ But when I try to use telnet to send an email to an external mail, for example to my gmail I will never receive it. here is my main.cf file

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Raspbian)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.

compatibility_level = 2



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_d$
myhostname = domain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, example.xyz, domain.com, localhost.com, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128

mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
myhostname = example.xyz
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mailbox_command =
```

(All the Example.xyz were replaced for the domain pointing to the raspberry pi ip)

Here is the response by using telnet

```
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 example.xyz ESMTP Postfix (Raspbian)
ehlo example.xyz
250-example.xyz
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250-SMTPUTF8
250 CHUNKING
mail from: poncho@example.xyz
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to: mymail@gmail.com
250 2.1.5 Ok
data
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Subject: test
Test
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as E8BA9DD6B6
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

But I never received the mail to my gmail

Comment: Did you check with `mailq`? Did you check the mail logs? Did you check DNS?

Comment: @Bib, where can I check mail logs?, also yes, DNS is pointing to the raspberry pi public ip